# Add Insert new row between two existing rows in bounded DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I tried to Add insert new blank row between two existings rows in datagridview (already bound to database) but I am getting following exception:

> Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound

My Code

```
private void load()
{
    string strProvider = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\AMOL\Desktop\Maratha.accdb";
    string strSql = "Select * from Maratha";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, con);
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable scores = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(scores);
    DGMaratha.DataSource = scores;
}

public void BtnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int row = (this.DGMaratha.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
        int column = (this.DGMaratha.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex);
        load();
        this.DGMaratha.CurrentCell = this.DGMaratha[column, row];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}

private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int row = (this.DGMaratha.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
    DGMaratha.Rows.Insert(row, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when DataGridView is data-bound, insert items into DataSource:

```
int idx = DGMaratha.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
var table = (DataTable)DGMaratha.DataSource;
var row = table.NewRow();
table.Rows.InsertAt(row, idx);
```

Comment: HI its working but the issue is that when i enter any data and click on save button its saving but that account which i added in middle its go down ,so please help

Answer (score 0):

DGV, when bounded to DB, is more of display than of an array. Altering should be done, as mentioned above, by datasource modification.